# Won't update system - HTC Vivid

Tags: updates

My htc vivid won't update the system from the settings or check for updates on the phone. I keep getting "Error" server unavailable. I reset my phone to factory settings and it still has same error message. Why can't It update? How do I update it? It's original 4.0.3 won't let me download certain apps because it's not updated. Help!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official site](http://www.htc.com/us/support/htc-vivid-att/news/), version 4.0.3 is the most up-to-date version of Android released for the HTC Vivid (AT&T) phone, and no newer OS versions will be released for it by either HTC or AT&T.

There are 3rd-party ROMs available for this phone with more recent Android versions, including 4.3 Jelly Bean and 4.4 KitKat.  Installing these requires unlocking the bootloader on your phone, rooting it, and installing a custom recovery image.  This usually voids the manufacturer warranty.  There are tools such as [WinDroid Toolkit](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2437705) that make this process easier, but those are not without risk.  Head over to XDA-Developers [HTC Vivid sub-forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/htc-vivid/) and read up on the details.